# return modified value from a database table

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am in a situation where I need to fetch data from a table and for a certain condition I need to change a data. for exp. if a column has value 0 then return '-' else return actual value

Here is my example

```
declare @aa int=0
declare @ww nvarchar='-1'
select @aa
select case when @aa=0 then cast(@ww as nvarchar)
            when @aa>0 then @aa
        End aa
```

But it return always 0 if value is 0.

Please help me.

Comment: You need to specify a length for `@ww`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution

Here is the query

```
declare @aa int=0
select case when @aa=0 then '-1'
            when @aa>0 then @aa
        End  aa
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
DECLARE @aa INT=0
DECLARE @ww NVARCHAR(10) = '-1'
SELECT CASE @aa
         WHEN 0 THEN @ww
         ELSE @aa
       END aa
```